# Is there any way to make Gmail syncing more up to date

Tags: gmail

It seems to take forever before my phone become aware that I have read all my gmail messages on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the frequency by:

1. Going into Gmail;
2. Use the `...` to bring up the application bar, and choose "settings"
3. Press <kbd>synchronisation settings</kbd>
4. Choose a new value for the "Download new content" drop down.

Personally, I have it set to "as items arrive" and it is faster than the Gmail notifier application on my PC.

Comment: It would be good to note that this doesn't fix the "unread it on my phone, but Gmail how's unread" problem. You can always tap the refresh button to force it though